# How to add two timestamps in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I suppose to add two timestamps like '03:59:39','03:43:04' in SQL Server and i require the result like sum of the two timestamps is 7 hours 42 minute 43seconds.

Without any casting... can any one suggest on this?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(CAST(@t1 AS DATETIME) + CAST(@t2 AS DATETIME) AS TIME)` **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414622)** but with casting and loose data if timespan > 24h

Comment: Are there any rules about these dates? Could it be more than 24 hours? Do you need an hour value >24 or a day value? This is not a question of calculation (just use `date2-date1`) but a question of formatting. This will need some kind of conversion...

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type that supports *time spans* (as opposed to times of day). It's time of day datatype (`time`) doesn't support addition, since it doesn't make sense to add two times of day together.

Comment: Thanq @lad2025... its working... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TRY this

    DECLARE @TIME1 TIME(0)
        ,@TIME2 TIME(0);

    SELECT @TIME1 = CONVERT(TIME(0), '2013-07-20 03:59:39')
        ,@TIME2 = CONVERT(TIME(0), '2013-07-25 03:43:04');

    SELECT @TIME1 AS [@REQUESTEDTIME]
        ,@TIME2 AS [@TIMEINTERVEL];

    SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', @TIME1), @TIME2) AS FINALRESULT;

Try this one also

DECLARE @TimeVal TIME
    ,@TotalTime TIME;

SET @TimeVal = '03:59:39';
SET @TotalTime = '03:43:04'

SELECT @TimeVal
    ,@TotalTime
    ,dateadd(hour, DATEPART(HOUR, @TotalTime), dateadd(minute, DATEPART(MINUTE, @TotalTime), dateadd(ss, DATEPART(SECOND, @TotalTime), @TimeVal)))
```